# How do you archive multiple versions of the same article on computer folders?

Tags: workflow, backup-archiving

I have some articles that were accepted by different journals, translated into different languages. How do you archive your writing in those cases? By publication? So to know exactly what was sent and where, which also means duplicating images and other linked resources (I write in markdown)... or by date? Keeping everything in the same folder, which avoids duplication of files but also makes it hard to keep track of where the piece was sent?

Comment: Disk space is cheap.

Comment: Maybe use git for that

Comment: @Giulio This article "https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8359/archiving-papers-simulation-and-experimental-data-etc?rq=1" may be useful.

Comment: @imtaar Thanks. This is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

That's what version control is there for. I imagine that I'm not the only one who has their home directory under version control. (The other advantage of this is that my home directory looks exactly the same on all of the machines I typically use, and that's quite a few.)