# Best practice in versioning / backing up work?

Tags: publications, version-control, backup-archiving

When I work on a paper I end up with folders paperXYZ, paperXYZ_R1, paperXYZ_R2, etc. Same thing happens with my code, project material, etc. This creates clattering and confusion. In addition, I need to backup things very often, to make sure nothing gets lost. Finally, once a paper / project is done, I need to archive it somewhere with easy access and searchable.

For a long time I was using the old fashion *copy and rename the folder* and every week backup everything to an external hard drive. Then, I moved to keeping everything on Dropbox, this lived shortly because I ran out of space. Now, I am slowly migrating my **code** to git repositories (bitbucket.org) and I still copy and rename the folders for my papers.

My questions are:

- How do you keep the versions of your work, mainly concerning publications? But also other projects and code.
- Where do you backup your final versions (the editable material, not the final pdf)?

Points like easiness of use, safety of material, easiness to search, etc. are welcome.

**I know this is a subjective question (i.e. I know I'm pushing my luck), but I would like to see what people actually use and maybe get some ideas on what is considered best practice.**

Comment: Honestly, I find a versioning control system (e.g. git or SVN) useful for the papers too, especially if they're written in latex. Doesn't help with final storage too much though.

Comment: Also see: [Secure backups of PhD and journal-research](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10822/secure-backups-of-phd-and-journal-research), [Why use version control systems for writing a paper](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5277/why-use-version-control-systems-for-writing-a-paper), [Advantages or disadvantages of using public repositories for paper writing?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18426/advantages-or-disadvantages-of-using-public-repositories-for-paper-writing)

Comment: @ff524 Indeed it's the same question... i failed to find it when I searched. Should I delete my post?